# my python print trie function can't print - RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Tags: python, tree, trie

```
class Trie:

   
    def __init__(self):
        self.endword = False
        self.children = [None]*26
        
    def insert(self,word):
        curr = self
        for c in word:
            if curr.children[ ord(c) - ord('a')] == None:
                curr.children[ord(c) - ord('a')] = Trie()
            curr = curr.children[ord(c) - ord('a')]
     
        curr.endword = True

    def print_trie(self,cur):
        res = []
        curr = self
        if curr:
            if curr.children:
                
                for c in curr.children:
                    if c.endword == False:
                        for el in self.print_trie(c):
                            res.append(c + el)
                    else:
                        res.append('')
            return res
                    
        
        
    def search(self,word):
        curr =self
        for c in word:
            curr = curr.children[ord(c) - ord('a')]
            if curr == None:
                return False
        if curr.endword:
            return True
        return False
    
    def startsWith(self,prefix):
        curr = self
        for c in prefix:
            curr = curr.children[ord(c)-ord('a')]
            if curr == None:
                return False
        return True


main = Trie()
main.insert('apple')
main.insert('app')
main.insert('appetit')
main.insert('apples')
main.insert('tea')

main.print_trie(main)
```

The logic behind print_trie - print the first 'trie' (aka char) but my implementation does not have actual value.

Comment: You never call `print`. Maybe use `print(main.print_trie(main))`

Comment: `print_trie` seems to have a typo; you ignore the argument `cur`, then hard-code `curr` to be `self` on every invocation. You probably want something like def print_trie(self, curr=None): if curr is None: curr = self ....` That would also get rid of the redundant argument on the first call: `print(main.print_trie())`

Comment: @chepner, thx there is no way it's possible to make it iterative - only recursive print is possible

Comment: It's never impossible to replace recursion with iteration or vice versa, but using recursion here is fine, even if it's not a requirement of an assignment.

Comment: @chepner, no it's not a req-t,but still i changed the header of my print_trie - it's fine, but not showing actual words

Comment: As also pointed out, `print_trie` only *returns* a list of the words in the trie; it doesn't actually print them.

Comment: @chepner, ok, i did print it and it's None! here is the gist https://gist.github.com/erjan/185b9dae6c569ba88876353fccf03e07

Comment: That's because you only return `curr` when the initial value is `None`, which is only true on the first call. All recursive calls start with `curr` equal to some subtrie, and your `return` statement never gets executed. In other words, you have an indentation problem that only became apparent once `curr` was no longer hard-coded to be a truthy value.